# Is it possible to get values from query string with same name?

Tags: python, query-string, tornado

I want to know if it's possible to get values from this query string?

```
'?agencyID=1&agencyID=2&agencyID=3'
```

Why I have to use a query string like this?
I have a form with 10 check boxes. my user should send me ID of news agencies which he/she is interested in. so to query string contains of multiple values with the same name. total count of news agencies are variable and they are loaded from database.
I'm using Python Tornado to parse query strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading [the tornado docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.1/web.html), this seems to do what you want

> **RequestHandler.get_arguments(name, strip=True)**
>
> Returns a list
> of the arguments with the given name.
> If the argument is not present, returns an empty list.
> The returned values are always unicode.

So like this

```
ids = self.get_arguments('agencyID')
```

Note that here i used `get_arguments`, there is also a `get_argument` but that gets only a single argument.

---

You can get the whole query with

```
query = self.request.query
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> url = '?agencyID=1&agencyID=2&agencyID=3' 
>>> parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
{'agencyID': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

Comment: `from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qsl` for python3

Answer (score 2):

tornado.web.RequestHandler has two methods to get arguments:

- get_argument(id), which will get the last argument with name 'id'.
- get_arguments(id), which will get all arguments with name 'id' into a list even if there is only one.

So, maybe get_arguments is what you need.