# How to manipulate query string?

Tags: python, tornado

I get the query string using this command:

```
query_string = self.request.query
```

My query string is like this:

```
"channel_sort=trending&channel_time=6&keyword=&channel_prepage=16&channel_pageno=25&page_country=usa"
```

I want to change channel_pageno values to 1 instead of 25. I've done it this way:

```
def query_first_page(query):
    qs = query.split('&')
    qs_parts = {}
    for item in qs:
        temp = item.split('=')
        qs_parts.update({temp[0]: temp[1]})
    qs_parts['channel_pageno'] = 1

    list = []
    for key, value in qs_parts.iteritems():
        list.append(str(key) + '=' + str(value))
    return '&'.join(list)
```

My function is is working fine. but I think there must be a better way to do that, for example query string processing lib in or something like that. do you have any idea?

Comment: Related informations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030565/is-it-possible-to-get-values-from-query-string-with-same-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib

data = self.request.GET.copy() # or data = urlparse.parse_qs(self.request.query)
data['channel_pageno'] = 1

uri = urllib.urlencode(data)
```

You'll get modified query string in `uri`.

Answer (score 1):

try something like :

```
import re
query_string  = re.sub(r"channel_pageno=[0-9]+&", "channel_pageno=1&", query_string)
```

[re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) works like [str.replace](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm), using regexes. Here you look for `channel_pageno=` followed by at least 1 number and a `&` sign, and replace it with the correct value

This will replace all occurences of `channel_pageno=` though. If you want to replace only the first or customize your replacement further, refer to the documentation I provided